# Specifying CJK fonts for pdftex and CJK.sty

Tags: pdftex, cjk, japanese

I'm compiling a Japanese TeX file written with `CJK.sty`, and using the [IPA fonts](http://ossipedia.ipa.go.jp/ipafont/index.html). I used `ttf2tfm` to generate `tfm` files. Is there a way to tell `pdftex` that a set of `tfm` files correspond to one Unicode truetype fonts, directly from inside a tex file? I'm currently using

```
\pdfmapfile{+ipamp.map}
```

with the `ipamp.map` file of the form

```
ipamp00 <ipamp.ttf <ipamp00.enc
ipamp01 <ipamp.ttf <ipamp01.enc
ipamp02 <ipamp.ttf <ipamp02.enc
ipamp03 <ipamp.ttf <ipamp03.enc
... continuing to ipampff ...
```

which, I think, is rather stupid. Furthermore, the embedding of the fonts to the pdf file, which is done at the last stage of `pdftex`, is very slow. My question then is if there's a better way. For example, for `dvipdfmx`, you can just have one line

```
ipamp@Unicode@ unicode ipamp.ttf
```

Background: I'm preparing a Japanese TeX file for submission to a preprint server (arXiv) which doesn't unfortunately accept XeTeX or LuaTeX. The server only has the wadalab font for Japanese, which is rather ugly. So I'd like to use IPA instead. The way I described above works, but doesn't sound perfect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pdfTeX now supports one-line mapping syntax using a SFD file. It is undocumented. You can use

```
ipamp@Unicode@  <ipamp.ttf
```

instead of

```
ipamp00 <ipamp.ttf <ipamp00.enc
ipamp01 <ipamp.ttf <ipamp01.enc
ipamp02 <ipamp.ttf <ipamp02.enc
ipamp03 <ipamp.ttf <ipamp03.enc
......
```

And you can even use

```
\pdfmapline{=ipamp@Unicode@  <ipamp.ttf}
```

in your TeX file. Then you don't need to write a mapfile.

This method is used for Chinese years ago. You can have a look at `zhwinfonts.tex` in our `zhmetrics` bundle.

---

Full test for those who are not familar with `CJK` and CJK fonts:

1. Download IPA Fonts from http://sourceforge.jp/projects/ipafonts/releases/
2. Use this command line to make a lot of `.tfm` files:

   ```
   ttf2tfm ipamp.ttf -q -w ipamp@Unicode@
   ```

   and we have this map line on console:

   ```
   ipamp@Unicode@   ipamp.ttf
   ```
3. Write a `c70ipamp.fd` to install the font in LaTeX NFSS:

   ```
   \DeclareFontFamily{C70}{ipamp}{\hyphenchar \font\m@ne}

   \DeclareFontShape{C70}{ipamp}{m}{n}{<-> CJK * ipamp}{\CJKnormal}
   \DeclareFontShape{C70}{ipamp}{bx}{n}{<-> CJKb * ipamp}{\CJKbold}
   ```
4. Use this TeX file to test (UTF-8 encoded, compiled with `pdflatex`):

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \AtBeginDvi{\pdfmapline{=ipamp@Unicode@  <ipamp.ttf}}
   \usepackage{CJK}
   \begin{document}
   \begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{ipamp}
   日本語
   \clearpage\end{CJK*}
   \end{document}
   ```