# Installing mincho font for MikTeX 2.9 on Windows 7

Tags: miktex, cjk

I want to use Japanese Writing in my LateX document and for that I (think that) need to install the Mincho font, which is currently not fully available from mixTeX.

My Problem is that I need to be able to write some old japanese Characters which are not displayed when I use the following piece of code to write japanese:

```
\newcommand{\jap}[1]{\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}#1\end{CJK}}
```

What I did till now:

- I downloaded mincho-1-8-20080306.tar.gz from
  http://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/wadalab
- I installed the files in my MikTeX installation
- I changed the line of code from `\newcommand{\jap}[1]{\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}#1\end{CJK}}` 
  to 
  `\newcommand{\jap}[1]{\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min}#1\end{CJK}}`

I get the following error:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `C70/mincho/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `C70/song/m/n' instead on input line 146.

    ("E:\Program Files (x86)\MikTeX\tex\latex\cjk\UTF8\c70song.fd")
    ! Undefined control sequence.
    try@size@range ...extract@rangefontinfo font@info 
                                                      <-*>@nil <@nnil
```

I'd appreciate any help on that matter.
Especially I'd like to know where i can check if I installed the font correctly, or if there is any other way to get the characters showing that don't show with the "gbsn" font.

Comment: It looks as if files are missing (e.g. c70min.fd). Also you shouldn't use for your first tests a command with an argument like your `\jab`: This breaks if catcodes must be changed. But before wading more through the installation of fonts for CJK: Did you consider to use xelatex?

Comment: It seems that you did not properly install the font files. And it is really a pain to install CJK fonts for normal LaTeX users. I also suggest you to use XeTeX (via `xeCJK`) or LuaTeX (via `luatex-ja`).

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. It helps for instance users to try out, whether it works with there MiKTeX installation. This leads me to a second advice: `wadalab` can be installed using MiKTeX’ own installation routines. Do you have language support for CJK activated? Take a look into the MiKTeX settings, not under “Languages”, but under “Packages” – “Language support”.

Comment: See also my answer in [Specifying CJK fonts for pdftex and CJK.sty](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26798/specifying-cjk-fonts-for-pdftex-and-cjk-sty) to get an example how to install a set of CJK TrueType fonts.